# How should I go about making the names bold in this multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested

What would be the best approach, keeping similar structure, to bold the names only in this array?  I can get it working on the entire array (which I have here), but I'm just trying to get the names.  I have an idea of an ugly approach to this, but would appreciate some help on something concise and clean looking. Also, I know  isn't the best thing to use and I should wrap the array in an object etc, but that's not what I need here.  This ties into a bigger problem I'm thinking about and is practice for something larger in the future.  Thanks.

```
var people = [ 
  [ "Daniel",30,"San Francisco",["175 lb"," 6\'0\""] ],
  [ "Deryl",29,"Seattle",["165 lb"," 5\'9\""] ], 
  [ "Mandie",29,"Seattle",["155 lb"," 5\'8\""] ], 
  [ "Elena",28,"Seattle",["145 lb"," 5\'6\""] ]
];

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.write("<br>"+"<b>");
    for(var j = 0; j < people.length; j++) {
        document.write(people[i][j]+"<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second loop be `for(var j = 0; j < people[i].length; j++)`?

Comment: I believe you're correct there.  Only been at this a few weeks.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop to this...

```
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.write("<br/>");
    for(var j = 0; j < people[i].length; j++) {
        var text = people[i][j];
        if (j == 0) {
            text = "<b>" + text + "</b>";
        }
        document.write(text + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

It does the same as what you previously had, but it wraps the first element in each row with `<b>` tags.  There are better ways to do this, like using css and classes to identify the columns, and in the long run that will make it easier to maintain and modify, but for the sake of learning and fixing this one issue, this will suffice.

Also, there was an issue with the inner loop getting the length of `people`, rather than the specific row.  I fixed that by changing it to `people[i].length`.

Answer (score 3):

I've organised your code into an array of objects, heres why.  Firstly i think it makes the code **A LOT** more readable.  An array data can quickly become confusing, especially when you haven't looked at the code for a while.  Take this situation for example - you are recording the persons name, along with the names of his/her mother and father.  Your array would look something like this:

```
['Toby', 'Chris', 'Lyndall']
```

From that point onwards you will have to remember that:

```
array[0] //Persons name
array[1] //Fathers name
array[2] //Mothers name
```

Secondly, it means you can iterate over all the objects and easily reference any of their properties without having to reference multi-dimensional arrays which too can become confusing.

```js
var people = [ 
  {
    name: "Daniel",
    age: 30,
    location: "San Francisco",
    weight: "175 lb",
    height: "6\'0\""
  },
  {
    name: "Deryl",
    age: 29,
    location: "Seattle",
    weight: "165 lb",
    height: "5\'9\""
  },
  {
    name: "Mandie",
    age: 29,
    location: "Seattle",
    weight: "155 lb",
    height: "5\'8\""
  },
  {
    name: "Elena",
    age: 28,
    location: "Seattle",
    weight: "145 lb",
    height: "5\'6\""
  }
];

people.forEach(function(person) {
  var html = '';
  
  html += '<b>' + person.name + '</b>' + '<br>';
  html += person.age + '<br>';
  html += person.location + '<br>';
  html += person.weight + '<br>';
  html += person.height + '<br><br>';
  
  document.write(html);
});
```

Comment: I'm roughly aware of this approach.  Couldn't figure out how to keep it intact the way I had.  Will keep this in mind for more professional purpose(s).

Answer (score 0):

`people[i][0]` is the name, so output that one first inside the `<br>` tags, and then output the rest?

**Edit:** for readability, perhaps you should consider refactoring your array to contain JSON objects instead? You would then be able to get the person's name by `people[i].name`, for example.

Comment: Also, your inner for loop looks incorrect? Doesn't make sense to iterate people.length number of times when outputting data for each person?

Comment: What would be your approach to my problem?  Been at it for a minute and can't figure it out.  Pretty new to programming still.  How would you write it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try surrounding the first element in the array within each `people` element with a `br` tag.

```js
var people = [ 
  [ "Daniel",30,"San Francisco",["175 lb"," 6\'0\""] ],
  [ "Deryl",29,"Seattle",["165 lb"," 5\'9\""] ], 
  [ "Mandie",29,"Seattle",["155 lb"," 5\'8\""] ], 
  [ "Elena",28,"Seattle",["145 lb"," 5\'6\""] ]
];

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var props = people[i];
    if(props.length > 0) {
        document.write('<b>' + props[0] + '</b>&nbsp;');
        for(var j = 1; j < people[i].length; j++) {
            document.write(props[j]+"<br>");
        }
    }
}
```